# How do I seed the database for an application I have deployed to Heroku using Jaws DB?

Tags: heroku

I have my application deployed on Heroku, and JawsDB is installed as an add-on. I cannot find any documentation on seeding the database via CLI or otherwise. Can anyone point me to the correct documentation? I have a working dotenv file in my application build.

Comment: I don't understand the question. How would you normally seed it? Why can't you just do that?

Comment: I'm a student who normally tests on localhost. I run the schema through MySQL to define the db then seed the db using node.js in bash. I am having a hard time finding documentation on how to do this in heroku through the command line.

Comment: You just need to point whatever you normally do at the Jaws DB database, whose connection info [should be available via the `JAWSDB_URL` environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/jawsdb#provisioning-the-add-on).

Comment: Got it, thank you! This lead me to find how to access the Jaws DB MySQL dashboard.